# Statistics Problem - Statistical hypothesis testing and P-value related

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, standard-deviation, hypothesis-testing

***Exercise :***

*Five random concentration measurements have been taken from each of two points $A$ and $B$ of a river to check the pollution levels.*

*Point $A$ : $5.2 , 4.8, 5.0, 4.9, 5.1$*

*Point $B$ : $4.7 , 5.0, 4.9, 4.8, 4.9$*

***(a)*** *Are there serious evidence at the $1\%$ significance that the mean concentration at Point $B$ is less than the mean concentration at the Point $A$ ? Consider equal distributions for the concentrations at both Points of the river. What other hypothesis is/are needed ?*

***(b)*** *Find the p-value of the test.*

***(c)*** *Find a confidence interval with trust 95% for the standard deviation of the concentration at Point $A$.*

***Attempt :***

Let $μ_1$ : be the mean concentration of Point $A$

Let $μ_2$ : be the mean concentration of Point $B$

The statistical hypothesis testing will be :

$H_0 : μ_1 - μ_2 = 0$ against $H_1 : μ_1 - μ_2 > 0$

The number of the degrees of freedom is : $n_1 + n_2 - 2 = 5 + 5 - 2 = 8$

Now :

$$D_1 = 0.5, D_2 = -0.2, D_3 = 0.1, D_4 = 0.1, D_5 = 0.2$$

So: $$μ(D)=0.14$$

And :

$$S_D^2 = 0.063$$

So :

$$t= \frac{μ(D) - δ_ο}{S_D/\sqrt{n}}=\frac{0.14-0}{\sqrt{0.063}/\sqrt{5}}= 1.24722$$

I will have to check :

$$t \geq t_{a;n-1} \Rightarrow 1.24722 \geq t_{0.1;4}$$

and it will lead me to if it's true or not.

Now, I would like to ask $(1)$ is my approach correct ? And $(2)$ why does it ask if any more hypothesis are needed ?

For ***(b)*** and ***(c)*** I completely have no clue, so I would really appreciate a thorough solution and explanation, because it is one of the type of exercises I have to work for my end-term exams tomorrow.

Thanks in advance for your time ! I would really appreciate some help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: Read up on [two-sample pooled T-test](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/201) then go through the same set of steps I went through in [my previous answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2311993/statistical-hypothesis-testing-and-p-value/2312091#2312091), but using the null distribution for the pooled t test provided in the link. I'm not reproducing the pooled t-test link content here because its (a) good as is and (b) long.